# Is it possible to cross-compile D source code for MIPS?

Tags: d, mips, cross-compiling, mips32, texas-instruments

Is it possible to cross-compile D source code for MIPS?

For example, I want to compile a D "Hello, world." program that will run on TI AR7-based devices, which have MIPS32 processor and typically run Linux 2.4.17 kernel with MontaVista patches and uClibc (using the MIPS I generic target; ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1 SYSV).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI-AR7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reference compiler, `DMD`, does not generate `MIPS` code, so you'll have to use `GDC` and `LDC2`, which support generating code for whatever architectures their backends support (`GCC` and `LLVM`, respectively).

However, it's not a simple as generating the code. To get all of D's features workable, you'll need to port `druntime` and `phobos` to MIPS, as `druntime` is quite architecture specific. Without that, you'll be stuck without a GC, and all the features that entails.

So it is possible, but how possible definitely depends on how dedicated you are.

Comment: The question is if these devices are even capable of running a fully fletched GC in terms of resources.